# How to sort List<T> by result the function?

Tags: c#, wpf

I  wanted to insert the intersection point of edge some where on edge, but the edge could has intersection point before. So I wanted to sorted those intersection points between `Edge.Start` until `Edge.Finish` (those are `Point`).

to do the sorting I use `parametric T` equation, the function looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the value of T between startPoint and endPoint
/// </summary>
/// <param name="position">The intersection of edge</param>
/// <param name="startPoint">Start point of edge</param>
/// <param name="endPoint">End Point of edge</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static double calculateT(Point position, Point startPoint, Point endPoint){
    return (position.X - startPoint.X) / (startPoint.X  - endPoint.X);
}
```

and some where in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` i got this:

```
//there are some another intesection vertices

Node anotherPointer = new Node(); //pointer

//prev is node that points to start point of edge
//cur is node that points to end point of edge
//nodes is new node that wanted to inserted

//collection of intersection
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();


nodes.Add(node); //add the new intersection to the list

//grab all intersection between start point until end point

anotherPointer = prev.Next;
while (anotherPointer != cur) {
    nodes.Add(anotherPointer);
    anotherPointer = anotherPointer.Next;
}

//how to sort nodes?
```

the problem is I need three parameter to calculate `T` of intersection. how to sort `nodes` by function `calculateT` ?

***Note***

Here is my node class.

```
public class Node {
     Point info;
     Node next;
}
```

Comment: You can just use OrderBy(x=>condition here) , the one you wrote above or ,just pass the point to your function like x=> calculateT(x.Point,startPoint,endPoint)

Comment: no `OrderBy` function inside the `nodes`.. (:

Comment: add using  System.Linq;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
nodes.OrderBy(node => calculateT(...))
```

(I'm not sure how you get the parameters for `calculateT`, but you get the idea)

Comment: `OrderBy`is an extension method. You will need the namespace `System.Linq` in order for it to appear (add it to the `using` statements at start of the file). Be careful, as it will not modify the list, it will just return an ordered `IEnumerable<Node>`. You can then do whatever you want with it, including converting it to a `List<Node>`(with the aptly named `ToList()`method).

Comment: `OrderBy` is provided by Linq as an extension method of `List<>`.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` provides a [`Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) method you can use. This overload takes a [`Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate as a parameter, so all you have to do is build such a delegate from your `calculateT` method.

```
nodes.Sort((node1, node2) => calculateT( /* parameters using Node1 */).CompareTo(calculateT( /* parameters using Node2 */);
```

Note that if you want your `nodes` list to always be sorted using this method, you might want to use a `SortedList<T>`.

Comment: Why would he use this when there is OrderBy

Comment: @Coder1409 because OrderBy does not sort the list, it produces a fresh new `IEnumerable`, without changing the `List`. Which may or may not be what the OP needs, but is certainly not what he asked for.

Comment: I agree  it returns IEnumerable , anyway he can always reassign the resulting list to his List

Comment: @Coder1409 : don't do `myList = myList.OrderBy(v => SomeExpression(v)).ToList();` if you can avoid it. it will create a new `List` instead of reusing the same one, which may cause problems if the `List` is big enough or if you are in a context where garbage collection is expensive (I'm thinking of Unity, for instance)

Comment: Yeah I must agree on this too since he needs to use ToList() a new list will be created

Comment: @Coder1409 you could argue that in the majority of contexts the drawbacks don't matter. And that knowing how to use Linq may be the most important skill of a .Net programmer :)

Comment: Like you said it depends on the context , if it's matter of multiple users and each time a new list is created , it will be bad and will eat your memory,, +1 for your solution anyway